# Visual Studio 2013 installer crashes instantly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I've tried both the ISO and the web installer. Neither works, they both give the same error. I get the splash screen for a few seconds, and then a popup comes up and says that it has simply "stopped working." I've got the latest .NET installed (4.5.2), both Intel HD Graphics drivers and my NVIDIA drivers up to date as well. I've tried all of the solutions I can see that people had for this issue to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at  ActivityLog.xml and EventViewer (probably for errors in devenv.exe) to get more details.  And specify what version of VS13 and any Update packs you're trying to install. Also if you had any previous versions installed and if you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Comment: I checked out event viewer and apparently the installer threw a System.BadImageFormatException. Not sure about the ActivityLog.xml you're talking about, everything I'm seeing online is pointing to a folder in %APPDATA%\Microsoft that isn't on my computer. Any of this help?

Answer (score 0):

the full path of that folder would be c:\users(your user login)\App Data\Microsoft  . but make sure you have it set to see hidden files and folders.
And again - which VS13 are you trying?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. And do you mean \AppData\Local\Microsoft or \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft?

Comment: check both Local and Roaming (and if there's a 3rd one) for the file

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall:

```
"Intel HD graphics driver" (generic driver)
```

Or try an updated graphics driver.

It works for me in Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015.